# Establishing array of paired values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been reading a couple of books on Javascript and searching a lot on the net (most good answer seem to be here at stackoverflow) and I'm still uncertain how to proceed.

What I am after is to setup 2-4 players in a Javascript/HTML app so that it knows the player's real name, assigns an alias (later an avatar, but not now), starting points, and turns.

In a book by John Duckett, *Javascript & JQuery*, I learned that I can use either an Array or an Object. These are similar but work slightly differently.

For an array I might have something like this:

```
    var players= {
    Timmy = {alias: "Spike", turns:0}
     (and so on)
}
```

For an object I can apparently do something like this:

```
 var players= {
        Timmy = {alias: "Spike", turns:0}
        /* and so on */
    }
```

I'm not actually sure which is best, but I'm leaning toward the array. Where I'm stuck is that I am having a difficult time figuring out how to establish each player as such and create and populate the array with values, some of which will be selected randomly from a list (this part I can handle).

So I'm trying to start with a basic experiment (which as yet isn't working) that is less interactive than the rest of the thing I'm building, and populates the array with paired elements. Starting small with values for name and turns (all start at 0), I have this:

```js
var p1="Billy";
var p2="Mikey";
var p3="Sammy";
var p4="";
var playerList=[];
createPList();
function pListConstructor(name, alias, turns) {
 this.name=name;
 this.alias=alias;
 this.turns=turns;
}

function aliasChooser() {
 return alias
}
function createPList() {
 if(p1!=="") {
  playerList.push({pName: p1});
 }
 if(p2!=="") {
  playerList.push({pName: p2});
 }
 if(p3!=="") {
  playerList.push({pName: p3});
 }
 if(p4!=="") {
  playerList.push({pName: p4});;
 }
 document.getElementById("player1Disp").innerHTML=playerList[0].name;
 document.getElementById("player2Disp").innerHTML=playerList[1].name;
 document.getElementById("player3Disp").innerHTML=playerList[2].name;
 document.getElementById("player4Disp").innerHTML=playerList[3].name;
}
```

My thinking based on recent learning in JS and some decent experience a few years ago in Actionscript is that I should be able to use the push() method to add to the array with paired values, but so far I'm not having success.

Any hints or nudges are great! T

EDIT:
I've made some progress on learning how to populate the array, but the key issue is giving me a bit of trouble:

```js
var p1 = "sammny";
var p2 = "mikey";
var p3 = "Pete";
var p4 = "Rick";

var playerList = [];
var sCash = 0;
var pTurn = 0;
var currentPlayer;

var alias1 = "dickey";

/* store names by male and female for selection later */
/*SOLVED: Bad grammar never works in code! 
I used () instead of []  */
/* var aliasM = ("Spike", "Mike", "Pops", "Noodles", "Shorty");
var aliasF = ("Shanna", "Rose", "Sugar", "Alana"); */
//the right way:
var aliasM = ["Spike", "Mike", "Pops", "Noodles", "Shorty"];
var aliasF = ["Shanna", "Rose", "Sugar", "Alana"];

function aliasSelector() {
    if (Math.random() <= 0.55) {
        alias1 = aliasM[Math.floor(Math.random() * aliasM.length)];
    } else {
        alias1 = aliasF[Math.floor(Math.random() * aliasF.length)];
    }
    return alias1;
}
/*I realized I was missing the return here.
I fixed that, but now it is feeding back only the first letter of the elements? */

function playerGen(name, alias, turns) {
    this.name = name;
    this.alias = aliasSelector();
    this.turns = 0;
}

nameCheck();

function nameCheck() {
    if (p1 !== "") {
        playerList.push(new playerGen(p1));
    }
    if (p2 !== "") {
        playerList.push(new playerGen(p2));
    }
    if (p3 !== "") {
        playerList.push(new playerGen(p3));
    }
    if (p4 !== "") {
        playerList.push(new playerGen(p4));
    }

    document.getElementById("player1Disp").innerHTML = playerList[0].name;
    document.getElementById("player2Disp").innerHTML = playerList[1].alias;
    document.getElementById("player3Disp").innerHTML = playerList[2].turns;
    document.getElementById("player4Disp").innerHTML = playerList[3].name;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="player1Disp"></p>
    <p id="player2Disp"></p>
    <p id="player3Disp"></p>
    <p id="player4Disp"></p>
</body>
```

Solved and finished. Much of my programming experience has been in Actionscript, which is where my apparent insistence on using array = () instead of [] comes from. This little bit of learning and whatever helps me turn the corner in my development and in this little project I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: Your array and object examples look the same, and neither is quite legal syntax.  (The object one is close, all it would take is replacing the `=` with a `:`.)

Comment: Mixing the building of your objects with the rendering in HTML is likely to give you headaches.  I would suggest moving these lines out of the function: `document.getElementById("playerNDisp").innerHTML=playerList[N].name`

Comment: Ignoring the HTML lines, your code would properly build an array.  There might be better techniques, but this is one way to start.

Comment: Scott, I had a feeling that was not the best idea. Not sure what it was, but my gut said not to. Is the better approach to have one function call out the other (one for the build and one for the HTML) or to have a function that calls out both functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your two examples are identical, and define neither an object nor an array :).

That's what I would do if I were you (but I ain't, so I might be dead wrong):

First, forget about JavaScript and see what you need functionally.

I suppose you want to have a player *object* with a few attributes and methods.
Then I suppose you want an *array* of players (or a list if you want, but at any rate not an *object* with a different attibute representing each player).

Now the question is, how to do that in JS.

Basically JS syntax is very versatile. For instance, you can name the property **`p`** of an object **`o`** either in "object" notation (**`o.p`**) or in "associative array" notation (**`o["p"]`**).

The important point is, an object will not only be defined by its contents, but also by its class, which happens to be defined by the function used to create it.

For instance, if I define this:

```
function Player (name, alias, turns) {
    this.name=name;
    this.alias=alias;
    this.turns=turns;
}
```

I create an object Player with 3 attributes.
To create an instance of this object, I will use operator new like so:

```
var Bob = new Player ("bob", "killer", 123);
```

One might think you could just say something like:

```
var Jim = { 'name':'jim', 'alias':'greenhorn', 'turns':123 };
```

This could be actually equivalent if you were only to access properties. However, most objects are meant to have methods too.

Let's add a method "sayHi" to Player :

```
Player.prototype.sayHi = function() { console.log ("Hi, my name is "+this.name); }
```

Now we can use it with Bob:

```
Bob.sayHi(); // Hi, my name is bob
```

If you try it with Jim:

```
Jim.sayHi() // JS error : sayHi : no such property
```

What happens here is that `Bob` is actually of class `Player`, so when looking for a `sayHi`property, the interpreter will scan the `prototype` array, and since you defined `protopype.sayHi` (or `prototype["sayHi"]` if you prefer), it will use it.

`Jim` is a basic object, so naturally the interpreter has no means of finding a relation with a `sayHi` method.

Now if you use the bracket notation like in `var players = [];` you create an instance of an `Array` object, which has a lot of predefined methods (`push()` among many others).

So to create a list/array of players, you could use something like:

```
function Player (name, alias) {
    this.name=name;
    this.alias=alias;
    this.turns=123; // probably no need to pass this value as a parameter
}
Player.prototype.get_alias = function() { return this.alias; }

var players = [];
players.push (new Player ("bob", "killer"));
players.push (new Player ("jim", "greenhorn"));

console.log(players[1].get_alias()); // greenhorn
```

The `get_alias` method is actually not very useful, since you can't have private members in JS (or at least not in the same acceptation as in C++), so you could as well use `players[1].alias` directly, but I tried to stick to your original example.

Comment: Thanks kuroi neko! Your thinking and logic is along the lines of the book I mentioned: thinking out the process first, adding the code to make it happen second.

Comment: giving your answer a deep read and re-read and will probably create a fiddle as that seems to be easier than making a local copy.

Comment: question: Where the constructor is called out there: players.push(new Player("bob", "killer"));, can I put a callout to a function rather than a string, so that the names are generated randomly by another function?

Comment: Absolutely. You can do whatever you want in the "constructor" (the `Player` function). It is basically a JavaScript function like any other, except that when it will be called, `this` will refer to the object attributes. For instance I used it to set `turns` to a constant value, but you could as well set `alias` with something like `this.alias = generate_random_alias()`

Comment: Ah! I had thought of using the random alias generator in the callout of the constructor, but putting it inside the constructor makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Still working on it, but I have a fiddle going at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cartoonThunder/kcqp7gep/)